# How do I pronounce intervals like " x_1, x_2, x_3" written using subscripts?

Tags: pronunciation

I use eccentric notation. I have equations dealing with many sets of variables. I have 2 x's and 2 y's. x1 is a different base than x2, like when you have two separate functions with two sets of y/x values in ordered pairs.

Is there a way of saying "x_1" other than, "x underscore 1" or, "x sub(script) 1"?

Currently I am saying, "x one, x two, etc." I am not doing logarithms and do not think it appropriate to say, "x base 1" as is the convention for that and other positional notation.

Comment: I've always heard it as "x sub 1, x sub 2," etc.

Comment: @Robusto sees/hears it the way I generally do; in some cases, I use the same thing you are right now - "x one" "x two", etc.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: MathsSE (tag 'terminology').

Comment: Unless you want the exact literal terminology to be known, saying "x one" and "x two" is usually understood. Added verbiage may well detract from what you are trying to say *about* them.

Comment: When you say that it's a _different base_ do you mean that the numbers are different numerical bases, for example x1 is octal and x2 is hexadecimal? If not what do you mean?

Comment: The purpose of notation is to represent your argument. If your notation is confusing, change your notation. BTW, a number is a universal concept that doesn’t change when it’s represented differently. Your issue here is about symbols, not numbers.

Comment: Thank you Robusto and Jeff for confirming the same conclusions I had. To Edwin: I tried to use the math tag but I do not have enough reputation. I think someone from math told me I had to post it here.

Comment: To BoldBen: I am measuring the length of lines by pixels in a paint program. I am using notation to express two different lines as having two distinct lengths as base. I was making a picture using 4mm lines and 10mm lines. Each 4mm line is a base of 4mm, I refer to lines of this length as x1 while each 1mm line has a base of 10mm and is my x2.

Comment: To Global Charm: I refute that my notation is confusing. I insist on using it for clarity. Mathematically the values are understood, my issue lies with the language of how to speak it.